# How does augmenting Dispel Psionics work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, powers, psionics

In the Targeted Dispel section of the power description of Dispel Psionics it says:

> You make a dispel check (1d20 + your manifester level, maximum +10)
>   against the power or against each ongoing power currently in effect on
>   the object or creature. The DC for this dispel check is 11 + the
>   power’s manifester level.
>   (XPH, P. 94)

Augmenting this power works like this:

> Augment: For every additional power point you spend, the bonus on your
>   dispel check increases by 2 (to a maximum bonus of +20 for a 5-point
>   expenditure).

This has not been errataed, but I suspect the last paragraph should read "For every additional power point you spend, the **maximum** bonus on your dispel check increases by 2." This would enhance Dispel Psionics in a way that is close to "Greater Dispel Magic".

The text as given does not make sense to me, as *there is no +10 bonus on the check* that could be raised to 20 spending 5 points.

Is this assumption correct or are there other ways to interpret the way augmenting this power works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default bonus (to a d20 roll) on the dispel check is stated to be "your manifester level, maximum +10", and this power seems to further increase the bonus with a corresponding increase to the cap, such that augmenting it fully makes the dispel check bonus "+10 + your manifester level (maximum +20)", while augmenting it for only 2 power points makes the bonus +4 + your manifester level (maximum +14).

Comment: Ok, that is a possible interpretation  in keeping with the text.

Comment: The rules phrasing on this augment is a mess. "Possible interpretation that seems consistent with the text" is about as good as you're gonna get here.

Answer (score 3):

On EPH/p.94 under Targeted Dispel: One object, creature, or power is the target of the dispel psionics power. You make a dispel check (1d20 + your manifester level, maximum +10) against the power or against each ongoing power currently in effect on the object or creature.

On EPH/p.95 Augment: For every additional power point you spend, the bonus on your dispel check increases by 2 (to a maximum bonus of +20 for a 5 point expenditure).

When one augments Targeted Dispel, the augment which is 1 power point = +2 toward dispel check. 5 power points at maximum gives you +10 toward that bonus.

When making the Dispel Check (1d20 + your manifester level, maximum +10) and one wants to augment; the augmentation

For example: Rumi is a level 10 Psion and augments 5pp toward a dispel check giving her a +10 ) the +10 from the 5pp augment gets added to ones manifester level which is a maximum of +10, end result is (1d20 + manifester level, +10 max + augmentation, +10 max) this is where its mistaken as augmenting for 5 power points yields +20, Which is does not.

Also if Rumi were at level 12 for example she could not augment beyond +10 nor could she use 12 toward manifester level in the dispel check. The maximum is only +10 for both.

Comment: But the text explicitly mentions a *"maximum bonus of +20 for a 5-point expenditure"*. Your answer chooses to just ignore that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

1d20

+

> your manifester level, **maximum** +10

+

> every additional power point you spend, the bonus on your dispel
>   check increases by 2 (to a **maximum** bonus of +20 for a 5-point
>   expenditure).

vs.

DC = 11 + level of opponent

every point you spend increases both the total AND the maximum bonus by +2, for a total augmentation of +10, added to the maximum base of +10, for a GRAND TOTAL of +20.

However, if you were say, level 7 (since this can be manifested as low as level 5) and for whatever reason (Feats, Torcs, Surge, etc.) dumped all 5 extra points into this, your augmentation bonus would be +10,

but that +10 would only be added to 7, for a total of d20+17, not +20. Once you are manifesting at 10th level or higher, your die roll is as follows:

5pp: d20 + 10 (defeats 9th level rival on roll of 10+)

6pp: d20 + 12 (defeats 11th level rival on roll of 10+)

7pp: d20 + 14 (defeats 13th level rival on roll of 10+)

8pp: d20 + 16 (defeats 15th level rival on roll of 10+)

9pp: d20 + 18 (defeats 17th level rival on roll of 10+)

10pp:d20 + 20 (defeats 19th level rival on roll of 10+)

Vs. a difficulty that will generally be (11+1-20) 12 (1st level rival) to 31 (20th level rival).